# jQuery deferreds

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery deferreds. Here I have a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wadam1972/gEw2F/5/).

Can anybody tell me why the done function ("now it's my time") is fired before the other functions is done?

The guys in this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg723713) also create a deferred object and return a promise, so do I.
How must I change my little example to get the done function only fired after this 6 seconds (after the timeout)?

Thanks alot in advance
Wolfgang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass a function to the [done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) method, but instead you're calling `console.log()` immediately and passing its return value to `done()`. You should write:

```
$.when(test()).done(function() {
    console.log("now it's my time");
});
```

Instead of:

```
$.when(test()).done(console.log("now it's my time"));
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gEw2F/6/).