# Jquery deferred not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make 2 ajax calls. Second one should be called only when the first is finished:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

firstAjaxCall();

deferred.done(function () {
   secondAjaxCall();
});

function firstAjaxCall() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/SomeUrl',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
  });
}

function secondAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/SomeOtherUrl',
      type: 'Get',
    });
}
```

I also tried like this ([jQuery deferreds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381027/jquery-deferreds))

```
$.when(firstAjaxCall()).done(function() {
    secondAjaxCall();
});
```

but no luck.

Still, in the first example, sometimes the second call gets called first, sometimes it doesn't

In the first example the flow is like this:

```
firstAjaxCall();
secondAjaxCall();
deferred.resolve();
```

why is second call called first and before `deferred.resolve()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually return the Deferred from `$.ajax` to `$.when` to make that work

```
function firstAjaxCall() {
    return $.ajax({
        url  : '/SomeUrl',
        type : 'POST'
    });
}

function secondAjaxCall(data_from_first) {
    return $.ajax({
        url  : '/SomeOtherUrl',
        type : 'Get',
    });
}

firstAjaxCall().done(secondAjaxCall);
```

Comment: There's no need for `$.when()` here.  This could just be `firstAjaxCall().then(secondAjaxCall);`

Comment: @jfriend00 - that's true, I just added it because the OP was using it, and asking about deferreds

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call `secondAjaxCall()` in the success function of the first one
Like this :

```
function firstAjaxCall() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/SomeUrl',
    type: 'POST',
    success: secondAjaxCall()
  });
}
```